# Flutter : customize DatePicker ShowBottomSheet

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

**can someone tell me if there a package to customize the **DatePicker ModalBottomSheet**
or any another way to cutomize the DatePicker BottomSheet**

[image: Flutter ModalBottomSheet DatePicker]

Im trying to achive the same design of the DatePicker in the ModalBottomSheet
for Android and IOS.